# ajax response is duplicated

Tags: php, ajax

I've written an Ajax code, which calls a function in a php file.

```
queryURL = "http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/MyPhpFile.php";
params = fromDate+" , "+to_Date;
$.ajax(
{
    url: queryURL,
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data:
        {
            funcName: "MyFunc",
            values: params
        },
    complete: function (result) {
        debugger;
        doSth();

    }
});
```

And in my php file:

```
if ($_POST) {
if (isset($_POST['funcName'])) {
    if (function_exists($_POST['funcName'])) {
        G::LoadClass('case');
        $fName = $_POST['funcName'];
        if (isset($_POST['values'])) {
            $values = $_POST['values'];
            $arrP = explode(",", $values);
            echo call_user_func_array($fName, $arrP);
        } else {
            echo $fName();
        }
    }
}
}


fucnction MyFunc($fromDate, $toDate){
    echo "1";
}
```

In the Network tab of my browser's debugger section, I can see that the php file just called once. Yet the response is duplicated.
If my function returns 1, the response will be 11.

1. Why is this happening?
2. how can I prevent it?

Comment: You'll need to provide code samples that we can use to recreate the issue in order to help.

Comment: Without your code its hard to find out the issue you are facing. Post your code so that we can check your issue.

Comment: I've edited my question and add the codes

Comment: You have two `echo`, once inside the function and once outside…

Comment: Tip: you should not debug with "echo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `echo` from `echo call_user_func_array($fName, $arrP);`. Just use `call_user_func_array($fName, $arrP);`